# Mac style joined buttons (segmented control) with Gtk

Tags: gtk

I've seen it done in the ubuntu software center, and with a few gnome apps.

Where two buttons look like a single rectangle with a line through it, how is this being done?

Answer (score 1):

In GTK 3.0 and later, use the `INLINE_TOOLBAR` style class or `LINKED` style class.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from gi.repository import Gtk

button_names = [
    Gtk.STOCK_ABOUT,
    Gtk.STOCK_ADD,
    Gtk.STOCK_REMOVE,
    Gtk.STOCK_QUIT]
buttons = [Gtk.ToolButton.new_from_stock(name) for name in button_names]

toolbar = Gtk.Toolbar()
for button in buttons:
    toolbar.insert(button, -1)
style_context = toolbar.get_style_context()
style_context.add_class(Gtk.STYLE_CLASS_INLINE_TOOLBAR)

window = Gtk.Window()
window.set_size_request(200, 50)
window.add(toolbar)
window.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)
window.show_all()

Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Thankyou for your answer, I appreciate the time you've taken.  However I feel uncomfortable, I know the answers in there and I've looked before but found it difficult.  The only internet access I have is through my phone right now and it is cumbersome to use for that purpose.  I wish there were a developer wiki for this type of thing.  I'd feel happy to share my hard won GTK knowlege with people.  Doing anything beyond the basics is. A pain because of a lack of dev resources and fewer people who know what I ha bf e trouble with.

Comment: Yeah, quite a few of the new gnome config dialogs do where it's + / - boxes.  I'm quite tired and about to sleep, but I'm sure I've seen it popping up else where.

Answer (score 0):

Fwiw, since I recently had the same question, here's another answer with an up-to-date citation and using C instead of some wrapper. (I use GTKmm, but I feel we should refer to the native C API unless a wrapper is explicitly stated.)

I wanted to achieve the same thing and eventually stumbled upon the answer, at the official page [HowDoI: Buttons](https://wiki.gnome.org/HowDoI/Buttons). This effect is achieved by **putting the targeted `Button`s in a `Container` and giving the latter the CSS class *linked*.** (That page says using a `Box` is normal, but as`Box` will probably be deprecated soon and `Grid` is superior anyway... use a `Grid`.)

So:

```
GtkWidget *const grid = gtk_grid_new ();
GtkStyleContext *const context = gtk_widget_get_style_context (grid);
gtk_style_context_add_class (context, "linked");
/* Add your Buttons to the Grid */
```

That link also discusses some other handy embellishments we can make to `GtkButton`s, including the classes *suggested-action* and *destructive-action*.

For similar questions, it's very illustrative to browse the source of (A) an application that does what you want to replicate and (B) the Adwaita theme CSS.