# Python GTK3 Treeview buttons

Tags: python, ubuntu, gtk

With GTK3 some Treeviews (I presume) have a few buttons at the bottom that appear to be part of it. The System Settings in Ubuntu uses this, as well as the File Selector dialog for GTK3 apps

[image: Example treeview]

Is this a part of GTK3 or just a specially made container?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mac style joined buttons (segmented control) with Gtk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8277152/mac-style-joined-buttons-segmented-control-with-gtk)

Comment: This has been asked a couple times already, here's another: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617788/how-to-change-the-style-for-buttons-in-gtk

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In case anyone else comes here, the buttons are ToolButtons in a Toolbar with the "inline-toolbar" class

```
self.listTools=Gtk.Toolbar()
self.listTools.set_property("icon_size",1)
context=self.listTools.get_style_context()
context.add_class("inline-toolbar")

self.addButton=Gtk.ToolButton()
self.addButton.set_property("visible",True)
self.addButton.set_property("can_focus",False)
self.addButton.set_property("use_action_appearance",False)
self.addButton.set_property("use_underline",False)
self.addButton.set_property("icon_name","list-add-symbolic")
self.listTools.add(self.addButton)
```

I'm not sure if all the button specific properties are necessary

I packed the treeview above the toolbar an a ScrolledWindow and gave it these properties

```
scrolled_window = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
scrolled_window.add_with_viewport(self.objectsView)
scrolled_window.set_property("shadow_type","in")
```

Then finally I packed the ScrolledWindow above the Toolbar in a VBox

Answer (score 0):

The add/remove/up/down buttons are separate controls from TreeView. You'll have to add them to your UI and implement the behavior yourself.